# Android rich text Mark Down

Tags: java, android, text, formatting

I'm looking for a library or optimized examples on using 
Mark Down to create Rich Text.

For example, something to turn:

1 - *Bold* -> **Bold**

2 - _Italic_ -> *Italic*

Long example:

3 - _Hello_ *World* -> *Hello* **World**

And so on.

I've seen many apps use it, like Discord, Whatsapp, Skype.

I've done something similar, but I know it's not optimized and can lead to runtime errors.

Comment: See this https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Comment: You don't need a library to do this. Before looking for libraries try to figure what is available natively into Android SDK...

Comment: @Anikta that's a richeditor, not a mark down detector.

Comment: @Nirekin I know it's possible, I already did it. But I'm looking for an optimised way, something that won't use alot of CPU

Comment: @AhmadSattout changing the title of your question now makes the responses already provided obsoletes. If you really now want to know how to do that with **Mark Down**   you should ask a new question , or check if this has already been answered somewhere

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any extra library...

Just have a look into `android.text.SpannableStringBuilder`...

This will allow you to get text features like:

- Make it larger
- Bold
- Underline
- Italicize
- Strike-through
- Colored
- Highlighted
- Show as superscript
- Show as subscript
- Show as a link
- Make it clickable.

Here you have an example on how to apply a **Bold** style on a word in a TextView :

```
String text = "This is an example with a Bold word...";  

// Initialize a new SpannableStringBuilder instance
SpannableStringBuilder strb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

// Initialize a new StyleSpan to display bold text
StyleSpan bSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

// The index where to start applying the Bold Span
int idx = text.indexOf("Bold");

strb.setSpan(
                bSpan, // Span to add
                idx, // Start of the span
                idx + 4, // End of the span 
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        );

// Display the spannable text to yourTextView
yourTextView.setText(ssBuilder);
```

Comment: Yes, but you know where the word "Bold" is, but it's hard to find the letter "*" or "_"

Comment: You just have to look for the indexes of `*` and `-`... where is the issue?

Comment: Imagine looking through a string with 100+ letters, it's not time efficient

Comment: Maybe but what do you think an external library will do, it will look into the same string no?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look for library that support mark down

1. https://github.com/tiagohm/MarkdownView
2. https://github.com/noties/Markwon
3. https://github.com/IonicaBizau/medium-editor-markdown

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Your awesome text");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), start_int, end_int, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TextView tv=new TextView(context);
tv.setText(str);
```

Comment: That's easy to use when you know the start and end, not when you're trying to use Markdown

Comment: you should have some condition to make which text to make what format. without knowing that you cannot do any thing. And one more thing, any third party library will also use internally some concept to know the index of the text that you are going to format.